# IBM MQ ISSUE in Apache Camel because Spring JMS Listener

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I am new to IBM MQ with Apache camel. below is my configuration

```
<from IBM MQ>
<parallel>
 <to ACTIVE MQ>
 <to IBM MQ>
</parallel>
```

my application is running in Spring Container. some time I am getting this below warning, hence My route is not working ( IBM MQ is not reading msg). for getting warning, Route is not working .

Exception

> org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer handleListenerSetupFailure
>   WARNING: Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'temporary' - trying to recover. Cause: User XXXXXX is not authorized to create: temp-queue://ID:IP Address-1:26:1
>   Feb 20, 2015 2:59:07 AM org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful
>   INFO: Successfully refreshed JMS Connection
>   Feb 20, 2015 2:59:08 AM org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer handleListenerSetupFailure
>   WARNING: Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'temporary' - trying to recover. Cause: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE'.; nested exception is com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').**

I am using Active & IBM MQ, why  Spring JMS Listener is throwing warning ?

Comment: Camel is trying to create a temporary queue (my best guess for a request/reply scenario) and the user that you have configured does not have the right to do that. It's all written in the stacktrace and the Spring JMS support has nothing to do with that.

Comment: please tell me Why camel should create temporary queue while posting msg to another queue?. If I change to inonly pattern will it work and will I get deadLetterchannel call for retry logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make sure you don't have request-reply specified as [exchange pattern](http://camel.apache.org/exchange-pattern.html).

I would explicitly state that the message should be "InOnly".

```
 <inOnly uri="ACTIVEMQ..."/>
 <inOnly uri="IBM MQ..."/>
```

If you intend to do a request/reply, then you need to make sure your WebSphere MQ user has rights to access SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE.

Something like this should allow authority:

```
setmqaut -m QMGR -t q -n SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE -g mygroup +dsp +inq +get
```

Comment: Thanks for valuable reply. why inout pattern trying to read default queue( SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE). this is not happening for another queue<from IBM MQ><to IBMMQ>. if I give inOnly , in-case the queue is down will I get deadLetterchannel call for retry logic. please answer my questions

Comment: Well, if camel decides it should do a request/reply over JMS, it will attempt to create a temporary queue for the response. In IBM WebSphere MQ, by default - you need to access to the model queue to create a temporary reply queue. On complex routes, it's often wise to explicit state the exchange pattern to inOnly.

Comment: For request/reply you can use named queues, eg replyQueue=foo to use a queue named foo. Read all about it on the Camel JMS documentation page.